# Unable to upload APK with Google Play Services 6.1 to the Play Store

Tags: google-play-services, chromecast, google-cast

I updated the Play Services SDK because I heard there were new Chromecast features, but when I try to upload an APK built with the latest Google Play Services I get the following error:

```
You uploaded an APK that uses Google Play services version 6111000. You need to use version 5100000 or lower.
```

I tried changing the meta-data to use an older version (5100000) and the app just crashes with an error that says `Expected 6111000 but found 5100000`

So what are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have pushed a fix for that, please try again and see if that is fixed or not; it may take a little while for the fix to propagate globally but should be there very soon.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happens to me too. Personally I am going to wait for a few days until google fix this. But you can download an older version [here](http://dl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_5089000_r19.zip)

Comment: I was told by their Play Dev Console help that it won't be enabled until L is released but he also told me to just change the meta-data which didn't work so I'm not sure how much he knew.

Comment: yeah changing the meta-data won't work so your best bet is to download an older version I may do that too cause i can't wait for so long to update my apps

Comment: It has been fixed now.